# How Do You Write Files to IPFS via the HTTP API in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, post, ipfs

Could someone demonstrate writing a file to IPFS via the HTTP API (/files/write) and Python?

My code is getting messier every time I modify it.

https://pastebin.com/W9eNz1Pb

```
def api(*argv, **kwargs):
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/"
    for arg in argv:
        arg = arg.replace(" ", "/")
        if arg[:-1] != "/":
            arg += "/"
        url += arg
    url = url[0:-1]
    if kwargs:
        url+="?"
        for val in kwargs:
            if val != "post":
                url = url + val + "=" + kwargs[val] + "&"
        url = url[0:-1]
        print(url)
    try:
        if "post" in kwargs:
            print("POST DATA")
            with urllib.request.urlopen(url=url, data=urllib.parse.urlencode(kwargs["post"]).encode("ascii")) as response:
                return response.read()
        else:
            with urllib.request.urlopen(url, timeout=300) as response:
                return response.read()
    except:
        return b"""{"ERROR": "CANNOT CONNECT TO IPFS!"}"""
```

```
class file(object):

    def __init__(self, p):
        self.p = p
        if self.p[0] != "/":
            self.p = "/" + self.p

    def read(self):
        return api("files", "read", arg=self.p).decode()

    def write(self, s, *argv):
        if argv:
            return api("files", "write", arg=self.p, offset=str(argv[0]), create="True", parents="True", post={"Data": s})
        else:
            return api("files", "write", arg=self.p, truncate="True", create="True", parents="True", post={"Data": s})
```

file.read() works perfectly. But file.write() is being a pain in the rear.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a minimal example to write a file via the `/files/write` HTTP API in Python:

```py
import requests, urllib

NODE = "http://localhost:5001"
FILE_PATH = "./example" # path to file you're trying to add
MFS_PATH = "/example"   # mfs path you're trying to write to

response = requests.post(NODE+"/api/v0/files/write?arg=%s&create=true" % urllib.parse.quote(MFS_PATH), files={FILE_PATH:open(FILE_PATH, 'rb')})
```

Answer (score 0):

- make sure ipfs daemon is running

  ipfs init
  ipfs daemon
- your url endpoint is wrong. If you check [documentaion](https://docs.ipfs.io/reference/http/api/#http-status-codes), for adding file,  url should be

  ```
  url = "http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/add"
  ```
- create a function to upload so u can use this logic in other parts of your project:

  ```
  def add_to_ipfs(filepath):
    from pathlib import Path
    import requests
    # rb means open in binary. read binary
    with Path(filepath).open("rb") as fp:
        image_binary=fp.read()
        # we need to make post request to this endpoint.
        url = "http://127.0.0.1:5001/api/v0/add"
        # check the response object
        response = requests.post(url, files={"file": image_binary})
        ipfs_hash=response.json()["Hash"]
         # "./img/myImage.png" -> "myImage.png" split by "/" into array, take the last element 
        filename=filepath.split("/")[-1:][0]
        image_uri=f"https://ipfs.io/ipfs/{ipfs_hash}?filename={filename}"
        print("image uri on ipfs",image_uri)
        return image_uri
  ```

this is the `Response` type from `ipfs`

```
{
  "Bytes": "<int64>",
  "Hash": "<string>",
  "Name": "<string>",
  "Size": "<string>"
}
```